# How to securely connect personal Mac OS X 10.9.2 to the live server database for data processing of tables?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, localhost

I tried to connect to my main server database using the below setup, but I'm getting the following error `mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on ***************** (60) in /Applications/AMPPS/www/tm.php on line 5`:

```
$DB_HOST = 'server.domain.com';
$DB_USER = '********';
$DB_PASS = '********';
$DB_DATABASE = "jackson";
$DB_PORT = "3306";
$db_connect = mysqli_connect($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_DATABASE, $DB_PORT);
$utf8= mysqli_query($db_connect, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

Could you please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Why don't you try yourself?

Comment: So, you decided to make too many questions instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the server credentials on your database settings.

```
$DB_HOST = 'database_ip';
$DB_USER = 'database_username';
$DB_PASS = 'database_password';
$db_connect = mysqli_connect($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS);
$utf8= mysqli_query($db_connect, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

And you're good to go.

Comment: SalustianoMuniz, thanks for your answer. I get this error after executing the file `mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on ***************** (60) in /Applications/AMPPS/www/tm.php on line 5`